# Django RawSql query to do filter on nested json

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset

My Models looks like this

```
class Foo():
  payload = JSONField()
```

Payload looks something like this

```
[{
  "id": 12,
   "names": [{"location": "New York"}, ]{"location": "Philly"}]
 },
 {
  "id": 15,
   "names": [{"location": "Paris"}, ]{"location": "Cannes"}]
 }]

queryset = Foo.objects.all()
queryset = queryset.filter(payload__names__contains=[{"name": "Paris"}]) #this works!!
queryset = queryset.filter(payload__names__contains=[{"name": "Par"}]) #does not work
```

The second statement does not work - it returns 0 results. In the first case it works because the full text is provided. What is the best way to do this in rawSql? [I am assuming it is not possible in Django]

I went thorough this but cannot find what to use to do `like` on a nested array json field.

Comment: This question may be related:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349889/how-to-use-a-regular-expression-to-extract-json-fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be done as seen here - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/

My solution is to implement RawSql something like this - [jsonb query with nested objects in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108179/jsonb-query-with-nested-objects-in-an-array/44714986?noredirect=1#comment76428303_44714986)