# How to create regex

Tags: regex, jmeter

can somebody help me how to create regex from this? I need only text after `a_n: "` so I need only this text. e.g. *jgoijODIJGojsklfj4dgdg_797gsdg-df_gsdfh-dhfGSDhfdsg-dfg*

```
{
  "a_n": "jgoijODIJGojsklfj4dgdg_797gsdg-df_gsdfh-dhfGSDhfdsg-dfg",
  "type": "something",
  "uuser": "userid",
  "expire": "6018"
}
```

Comment: This looks like json. Have you tried using a json parser to load and extract it?

Comment: It is response from post request and I need to use this value in next request header. I need it for jmeter so the best way should be regex or xpath..

Comment: regex and xpath are two entirely different things, and both aren't really suited for your use case I would think. Also you should give more context to your question - eg. use case, programming language, how the data will vary.

Comment: I have in jmeter POST request and in response data is text that I posted. I need from this text use value of a_n: in next request header. I was using for something similar (xml response) xpath extractor or regex extractor in jmeter. There can be used also some javascript, or beanshell script but I thought it would be easier via regex as I am not very familier with scripts...

Comment: Can you see if the answers to this question are helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562060/jmeter-extracting-fields-parsing-json-response ?

Comment: Thanks to all. I have installed json extractor plugin to jmeter so I am trying with this, but if can somebody help me also with json it would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jmeter extracting fields/parsing JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562060/jmeter-extracting-fields-parsing-json-response)

Comment: it is working with json extractor, thanks to all
`$.a_n`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with [JSONStream](https://npmjs.com/packages/JSONStream).

```
cat file.json | JSONStream '.a_n'
```

And also with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
jq .a_n file.json
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can, just use a JSON parser to get the value. Otherwise you can use

```
/{.*\"a_n\": \"(.*)\".*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look ([how to use a regular expression to extract json fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349889/how-to-use-a-regular-expression-to-extract-json-fields))

regex should be,

```
/"a_n":\ ?"((\\"|[^"])*)"/i
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract this in JMeter:

1. Add a [jp@gc - JSON Path Extractor](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) under your request sampler.
2. To extract the required data, you have to set like this:

[image]

3. Your extracted value will be saved in the variable `Jsonvar`.
4. Now You can use this variable other subsequent requests.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter's [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) uses [Perl-5 style regular expressions](https://www.pcre.org/) so the relevant configuration would be:

- Regular Expression: `"a_n": "(.+?)"`
- Template: `$1$`

Also be aware that it makes more sense to use [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) to work with [JSON](http://www.json.org/) responses. The relevant [JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) query would be as simple as `$.a_n`

Demo:

[image: JMeter JSON Path Extractor]

More information: [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)