# Extract values from JSON individually in Tablau

Tags: regex, string, tableau-api

I have a column in Tableau containing JSONs which are formatted like this:

```
{'10.0.0.4': 989, '10.0.0.3': 976, '10.0.0.5': 959, '10.0.0.2': 276}
```

Now I would like to create 4 new columns in the table with the four keys of the JSON. 
I know that I have to use `REGEXP_EXTRACT()`for this.

---

To describe it more generic:

I need a REGEX to retrieve `276` from

```
{'10.0.0.4': 989, '10.0.0.3': 976, '10.0.0.5': 959, '10.0.0.2': 276}
```

only with the usage of "10.0.0.2".

Can anyone help me or provide another solution?
Thanks.

Comment: With the edit I finally understood your question.  How would you imagine an regexp formatting your input into a JSON file?   You need to have a program to do that (e.g. JavaScript - https://codeblogmoney.com/convert-string-to-json-object-using-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

Extract the value of a key/value pair from a JSON string in Tableau:

In this example we want the value of a key called highwaytype, eg:
{"highwaytype":"motorway"}

The regex is via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349889/how-to-use-a-regular-expression-to-extract-json-fields and tested with http://regexr.com

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT([JSON Column],'"highwaytype":"((\\"|[^"])*)"')
```

Here is a variation to get the value of a float, removing a trailing comma after the value using !,:

```
float(REGEXP_EXTRACT([Weather],'"temp":((\\"|[^"!,])*)')
```