# Extract value of a field form json-like string using PHP Regex

Tags: php, regex

I need to extract value of a json field by regular expression, (I can't use json decode).

let's say for this string:

```
"url":"http://stackoverflow.com/orwell", "domain":"netcharles.com", "title":"Orwell Essays & Journalism Section - Charles George Orwell Links", "tags":["orwell","writing","literature","journalism","essays","politics","essay","reference","language","toread"], "index":2931, "time_created":1345419323, "num_saves":24
```

I want to get value of `domain`, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349889/how-to-use-a-regular-expression-to-extract-json-fields)  and some other solutions, they almost worked when I tested them in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/RFj16w/1) but when using PHP, they [didn't work as expected](https://3v4l.org/SrnF6); any idea why?!

String may or may not have a blank space after comma and before double quotation mark.

**UPDATE:**
the string is not exactly json, and it's not consist enaugh to convert it to a json by adding brackets, only part of string is like json.
It always contains something like `"name": "david","email": "some email"`, and I need to get data from that part, the structure of string is
`(anything here) "field1": "value1", "field2":"value2" (anything here)`

Comment: Is the string consistent enough to just add the {} round the string and then use as JSON.

Comment: If it's a JSON field, why can't you use `json_decode`?

Comment: @NigelRen no it's not,

Comment: One of the problems is that if the string is not consistent - how can you know the format is the same and you can extract the data using a regex? (Also please include the things you've tried in the question - links mat be deleted and so the question no longer contains information that would be useful to future readers)

Comment: @Nick It's not exactly json, only part of the string is like json, lets say something like `a word - "name": "david","email": "some email"  some other string 100-`

Comment: Maybe it's the backslashes? In PHP "\\" means a literal backslash, so your pattern should be: `'/"(domain)":"((\\\\"|[^"])*)"/i'`. See: https://3v4l.org/t42iO But really, if you have "not exactly json", can't you make it exactly json? That would be so much better than a regular expression.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware well, it looks ok. what is the last item of array  (string(1) "m") in result?

Comment: Why don't you just use `'/"domain":"([^"]*)"/i'` ?

Comment: If you look at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/RFj16w/1) the coloring indicates that the last "m" is the last letter of "netcharles.com". Weird isn't it? Anyway, you can now execute the correct regular expressions in PHP, which is a win, isn't it?

Comment: @Olivier I guess i should read more about regex, thanks.

Comment: @Oliver and @MohammadSalehi : Better not simplify the regex to just `/"domain":"([^"]*)"/i` because if the value contains a double-quote (which would be escaped with a backslash) then the match would stop too early. But yes, normally we should not meet a double-quote inside a domain, for sure. The use of `(?:\\"|[^"])*` is to say *"match a backslash followed by a double-quote or any char which isn't a double-quote, 0 or multiple times"*, which is a good logic as it will work for any other JSON string value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a problem of number of backslashes in your pattern.
I know, it's rather weird because you can effectively write a
PHP single-quoted string such as `'\s'` and the backslash will
be considered as a backslash. But if you write `'\\s'` it will
contain the same string. So sometimes, to make things easier
in regular expression creation in PHP, you can use the
[nowdoc syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc).

The nowdoc syntax will treat the string literally, so backslashes
will be taken as they are. Just like single quoted string, it also
doesn't evaluate its content, so doesn't look for variables inside
its content, in opposite of the double-quoted strings or the
[heredoc syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

It works with this code, using the nowdoc syntax, for a better
understanding of the regular expression:

```php
<?php

$subject = '"url":"http://www.netcharles.com/orwell/essays.htm", "domain":"netcharles.com", "title":"Orwell Essays & Journalism Section - Charles George Orwell Links", "tags":["orwell","writing","literature","journalism","essays","politics","essay","reference","language","toread"], "index":2931, "time_created":1345419323, "num_saves":24';

$pattern= <<<'END_OF_PATTERN'
/"domain"\s*:\s*"((?:\\"|[^"])*)"/i
END_OF_PATTERN;

$success = preg_match($pattern, $subject, $match);
if ($success) {
    var_dump($match) ;
} else {
    echo 'not match';
}
```

I removed the first capturing group around "domain", as there's no
need to capture it. I also added `?:` inside the inner repeating
capturing group to make it non-capturing. I don't see any reason
to get the last character of the domain value.

You can also create a named capturing group with `(?<group_name> )`.
This is what I did here: https://onlinephp.io/c/9b024